# Limit user in Fauna DB to read only his own data

Tags: faunadb

We are using FaunaDB for storing users and users movie collection. For accessing data in Fauna Functions we use secret key which is binded to Roles.
Users document looks like this:

```
{
username:"John Doe",
email: "john@doe.com",
userID: "124"
}
```

Movie Collection document looks like this:

```
{
userID: "124",
movies:['Titanic','Forrest Gump']
}
```

To query user movie collection we call fauna function with role user and specific secret key generated for that role

```
Call(Function("Get_users_moive"), '124')
```

I would like to know is to possible to limit user, to query only his own data? In the function above if I give another userID it will retrun another user collection.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about your infrastracture, but typically users must not have direct access to the database, they must be calling your backend, then your backend handle authorization, authentication and do query to the database only if user is allowed to do that specific action they tried to do.

Comment: Yes we have backend function which accepts accessToken from frontend, check validity of token and then takes userID from token to call fauna functions, but I tought for extra protection to add this limit in Fauna if possible?

Comment: I've never heard of that "extra protection", usually there is no protection between internal services such as DB or microservices inside single network. You don't need it as far as your server network is not compromised. Once it is compromised, this type of protection won't help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this in Fauna. You can create "identity" documents in a Fauna database, and give those documents credentials that can be used to authenticate the user. Once a user authenticates, the secret for a token is created. From that point, the user can directly query Fauna using that secret, if you choose to allow them to do so.

In addition, Fauna has attributed-based access controls (ABAC). You define a role, which has two primary features: a privileges definition that lets you control which collections, indexes, documents, etc. that a user with the role has, and a membership definition which lets you specify which identities belong to the role.

A role's privileges and membership definitions can use predicates: functions that can make a dynamic determination of whether a privilege, or the membership should apply to the current query.

You can find out more in the documentation:

- [Tokens](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/security/tokens)
- [ABAC](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/security/abac)

To ensure that a user can only access movie records that they created, you'll need to store a reference to the identity document within each movie document.

When a user uses the secret for the token that they acquired via the `Login` function, a role predicate can use the `CurrentIdentity` function to retrieve a reference to the associated identity document, and then compare that to the reference stored in the movie document. If those match, you grant read access, otherwise you don't.

For details, see:

- [Login](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/login)
- [CurrentIdentity](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/currentidentity)